# Is there anyway to stop a Windows 10 laptop from waking up because of accidental keyboard interaction in a bag?

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, sleep, lenovo-laptop

I own an Lenovo Yoga 1470 (Lenovo Yoga 3 14")

And the problem with it is that when I put it to sleep, and put it inside my bag, it seems to bend little bit and turn on because of a keypress.

I tried to search in settings, and other suggestions from Google, nothing worked.

Does someone have a solution on how to prevent keyboard from waking up the laptop?

It’s important to note that I have Windows 10, and inside device manager settings in keyboard there is no option to disable waking up the PC.

Answer (score 0):

My Toshiba lappy has a "wake on keyboard" setting within POWER OPTIONS (not Settings). Yours might have that too. From the Start menu type "power options" (leave out the quotes, of course) to get to that menu.

Comment: Nope, I don't have that..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, most Windows laptops come with pre-defined, default shortcut-key combinations for various (mostly) hardware related functions.
This usually includes something to enable/disable the touchpad.

In my case *(Acer Aspire)* the shortcut-key combination to enable/disable the touchpad is: <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd>. Yours may be different.
You can normally tell by closely inspecting for tiny images, (depicting secondary functions) printed on/above the actual keys, themselves.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have an keyboard disable switch, and I believe there must be an siftware solution

Comment: @Anonymous What exactly do you mean by "software solution"; what exactly are you hoping/looking for? I'll see what I can come up with. Also, how is there keyboard interaction in the first place? Don't you close the actual lid before you stow it away in your bag?

Comment: I see that other people have an option in the driver/keyboard settings to disable the device to be able to wake the computer, and the thing is that I do put in the bag with the lid closed, but since my backpack is packed with things, the lid bends and presses a key, I am 100% sure this what happens since if I put the laptop on my knee and press it down it turns on

Comment: @Anonymous is it definitely the keyboard? Try disabling the touchpad. See if it helps.

Comment: I can't disable the touchpad from options, with the keyboard key it still happens, and it is defenatily the keyboard since I tried it with an ruler while the laptop was sleeping...